# Lowest common ancestor explain code for binary search tree

Tags: c++, algorithm

I came to that problem here and I want someone to explain the solution, I can't figure it out.

```
TreeNode* lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* p, TreeNode* q) {
    while(root != NULL) {
        if (p->val < root->val && q->val < root->val) {
            root = root->left;
        } else if (p->val > root->val && q->val > root->val) {
            root = root->right;
        } else {
            return root;
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You should try editing it.

Comment: I want someone to explain the code, that's it

Comment: @AndreAhmed That's not really a question. You might want to ask a teacher/tutor about it.

Comment: It locates the first node where the given nodes are in different subtrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LCA of p and q in binary search tree is the shared ancestor of p and q that is located farthest from the root.

What your code does is, you are traversing from top to bottom, the first node n it encounters with value between p and q, i.e., p < n < q or same as one of the p or q, is LCA of p and q (assuming that p < q).

So just recursively traverse the BST, if node’s value is greater than both p and q then our LCA lies in left side of the node, if it’s is smaller than both p and q, then LCA lies on right side. Otherwise root is LCA (assuming that both p and q are present in BST)